# Peak detection in noisy waveforms

Tags: discrete-signals, time-series, smoothing, peak-detection

I have a set of `1-dimensional` time-series, a subset of which contain *either* one or two peaks, and the remainder of which are pure noise. I've smoothed these data by taking a simple rolling average. My goal is to, for those series which contain a peak(s), obtain both the location and value of that peak(s). *Ideally*, I'd like to find the location of the true inter-sample peak, as opposed to simply the location of the sample with maximum value.

I've tried a few things and, while (for the most part) all of the standard algorithms are able to find the peak locations, the algorithms also give the locations of tens or hundreds of samples which are non-peaks. I've tried:

a) A variety of "zero-crossing" algorithms

b) An implementation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data) "z-score" algorithm

c) [This](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Etoh/spectrum/PeakFindingandMeasurement.htm) simple threshold-based algorithm

Here's a sample of my (again, pre-smoothed) data. Two contain peaks (boxed in red), and one is pure noise (vertical axis not to scale):

[image]

Comment: have you tried putting the heights of the top-10 peaks into relation? Like, if there's a large gap between the highest and the second highest, or between the second and third highest, you might have a case of peaking? Other than that, I must honestly say, I don't see clearly with my very human eyes where the first two should have two peaks and the third example does not... that feels like you don't really specify a clear "condition" for "peak"

Comment: It seems the "peaks" are barely above the noise. With these non-parametric, "naive" approaches, it will be impossible to detect the actual peaks without too many false alarms, since essentially the SNR is very low. Do you know more about the nature of these peaks, how they come about? If there was an explicit signal model maybe a more parametric approach might fare better, but it is still going to be difficult in my opinion.

Comment: Have you considered using the analytic signal to give you the envelope of your waveform, and then from that you can more easily select a maximum value within a given time span? If any of this is not clear, I can provide further information as an answer. Ideally if you can post a link to your example data I can ensure first the approach I am thinking of would be valid for your signal